# Callback'и вызываются в новом потоке или том же?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Если я правильно понимаю, то в том же.

Однако, каким образом `Callback` на `Timer` вызывается в потоке из пула потоков?

> The method specified for callback should be reentrant, because it is called on ThreadPool threads. The method can be executed simultaneously on two thread pool threads if the timer interval is less than the time required to execute the method, or if all thread pool threads are in use and the method is queued multiple times.

Вроде, в [исходниках](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,703) не вижу явного создания нового потока...

Comment: В дотнете несколько таймеров, у каждого свое поведение. О каком именно речь?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, судя по ссылке на сорсы.Речь идет об этом https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

```
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [DllImport(JitHelpers.QCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    static extern bool ChangeAppDomainTimer(AppDomainTimerSafeHandle handle, uint dueTime);

    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [DllImport(JitHelpers.QCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    static extern bool DeleteAppDomainTimer(IntPtr handle);
```

В действительности, ваш коллбек вызывается сервисами CLR, которые используют потоки из пула. Из прототипов методов для создани таймера, видно, что потоки не сознаются в managed коде.[ref](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,18560a1c4f6f4f8d)

Answer (score 0):

Функция CallCallback уже выполняется в пуле потоков, надо смотреть кто ее вызывает. А вызвана она может быть двумя способами.

Первый вариант - из метода `FireQueuedTimerCompletion`, которая передается в пул потоков методом [`QueueTimerCompletion`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,420)

Второй вариант - из метода `AppDomainTimerCallback`. В исходниках coreclr видно, что он передается в пул потоков методом [`ThreadpoolMgr::FireTimers`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp#L4755)